# Word on Mac - keyboard shortcuts intermittently affect entire document when using custom styles

Tags: ms-office

Software:

- macOS: Sierra (10.12.6)
- Microsoft Word for Mac Version 15.39

I do a lot of work with documents that require identical formatting, so created a set of custom styles that will set up my entire document the way it needs to be. By this I mean that after setting the Heading style, pressing Enter will trigger the formatting to change to Subheading style, after which pressing Enter will change the formatting to the Body formatting.

I've noticed that recently (over the last couple of months) when I have to change formatting midway through the document in progress (e.g. bullet points/underlining/indent in the body of the text) the formatting will intermittently affect the entire document. It's fixable with a quick Cmd+Z but if I don't catch it at the time it's a pain to go back and fix the formatting again and again.

The only troubleshooting I have done (aside from a virus check) is updating the software and it hasn't fixed the issue (in fact, I had to re-create the styles I had made as they were removed from the Normal template). The problem only seems to happen after I have applied these styles (either to a new document from scratch or to an existing document); manually applying the formatting (Cmd+B, Cmd+I, Cmd+Shift+M, etc.) doesn't seem to cause the same issues. I'd like to keep using these styles but since I don't know much about software I don't know how to fix the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) It may be worth you [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/302307/edit) your question to include some additional info. For example, what version of macOS are you running? Also, can you clarify what you mean by: *It only seems to happen when I create a new document using these styles; regular formatting doesn't seem to cause the same issues.* If you start a document totally from scratch does it happen? What about if you open an existing document and then resave it for your new document?

Comment: @Monomeeth I've made some changes; is that enough additional information?